# General Relativity visualization software

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, software, visualization

As I am approaching the study GR, I was wondering if there are softwares that allow a quick visualization of custom metrics, curvature, and particle motion even in the limited context of 2D space.

Playing with equations is fun, but it would be more fun if I could play with various parameters and see the outcome.

Obviously free would be better, but I am open to commercial programs.

Comment: Related: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/85837/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking at this Java archive

> [General Relativity (GR) Package written by Wolfgang Christian, Mario
>   Belloni, and Anne Cox](http://www.opensourcephysics.org/items/detail.cfm?ID=7351)

It includes a lot of simple programs about Newtonian mechanics, special relativity and general relativity, including the aforementioned GROrbits.

It doesn't permit custom metrics - you are limited to Schwarzschild (regular and rain co-ordinates) and Kerr black holes.

Comment: Can this package calculate Gravitational Time Dilatation at Kerr BH's?

Answer (score 3):

For particle/light motion in 2D space, my nomination would be [GROrbits](http://stuleja.org/grorbits/)

It's free and requires a JVM to run, there is also a web start version for the brave ;)

Sorry but I've never found anything aimed at visualizing metrics or curvature (apart from plotting programs of course).